# Output .sol file Gurobi and Julia JuMP

Tags: julia, gurobi, julia-jump

How can I output a .sol file from JuMP? Im playing around with the lower level model but cant seem to figure this one out.

Using Gurobi and JuMP inside of Atom editor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the Gurobi parameters when you create the model and set the solver. The parameter is called *ResultFile*. More details about it can be found here:

http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/resultfile.html#parameter:ResultFile

Here is an example that worked fine for me:

```
m = Model(solver=GurobiSolver(ResultFile="MySolution.sol"))
```